# Get http status return ObjectDisposedException

Tags: c#, json

I'm trying to get the status code returned from http response, like this:

```
try
{
    HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(requestURI) as HttpWebRequest;
    string text

    using (HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse)
    using (var responseStream = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
    {
       text = responseStream.ReadToEnd();
    }

    var responseHeader = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
    var status = responseHeader.StatusCode;
}
catch (WebException ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
}
```

the problem is that I get this exception:

> System.ObjectDisposedException : "Cannot access to removed object Name: 'System.Net.HttpWebResponse'."}

on this line: `var status = responseHeader.StatusCode;`

why happean this? I want get the status code and the description

Comment: One of the few exceptions where dispose is actually called too often :-)

Comment: You are missing a ';' after `string text'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
using (HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse)
```

will dispose the response after leaving the using block.

So another call to `(HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();` will throw the exception. Additionally, because it's a web response, you cannot read it twice.

Try this alternative:

```
HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(requestURI) as HttpWebRequest;
string text;

HttpStatusCode status;

using (HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse)
using (var responseStream = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
{
   text = responseStream.ReadToEnd();
   status = response.StatusCode;
}
```

Comment: but if I want use the variable `status` also out the using? How can I do this?

Comment: You can bring the declaration outside the using statement just like you did with `text`. 'I'll update the answer but I am not sure of the return type.

Comment: uhm, okay but the `HttpReturnStatus` is underlined in red, no reference found

Comment: uhm, yes, as I said, I don't know the `type` ;-) , it's `HttpStatusCode` btw; https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebresponse.statuscode%28v=vs.110%29.aspx I edited it.

Comment: uhm okay now working, last question: for the `.StatusDescription` which declaration I should use? I tried with: `HttpStatusCode ` and `HttpWebResponse` and not working.

Comment: Looks like a `string`: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebresponse.statusdescription%28v=vs.110%29.aspx